# ansible-playbook: Unable to find subdir in expected paths with fileglob

Tags: ansible

I try to copy files from `roles/common/files` with `fileglob`, but `ansible-playbook` searchs them in `roles/common/tasks/files`

[Using Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles) documentation says:

> Any copy, script, template or include tasks (in the role) can
>   reference files in roles/x/{files,templates,tasks}/ (dir depends on
>   task) without having to path them relatively or absolutely.

Playbook:

```
# ./ansible/roles/common/tasks/main.yml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: setup bashrc
    import_tasks: bashrc.yml
```

Task:

```
# ./ansible/roles/common/tasks/bashrc.yml
- name: try to find bashrc libs in roles/common/files/bashrc
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /tmp
  with_fileglob:
    - bashrc/*.lib.sh
# Causes the same error:
#   loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'bashrc/*', wantlist=True) }}"
```

Files tree:

```
.
├── ansible
│   └── roles
│       └── common
│           ├── files
│           │   └── bashrc
│           │       ├── shell-aliases.lib.sh
│           │       ├── shell-functions.lib.sh
│           │       └── shell-settings.lib.sh
│           └── tasks
│               ├── bashrc.yml
│               ├── main.retry
│               └── main.yml
```

Run playbook:

```
$ ansible-playbook -vvvvv ./ansible/roles/common/tasks/main.yml
...
TASK [try to find bashrc libs in roles/common/files/bashrc] *******...
task path: /home/<user>/git/homedirsync/ansible/roles/common/tasks/bashrc.yml:1
looking for "bashrc" at "/home/<user>/git/homedirsync/ansible/roles/common/tasks/files/bashrc"
looking for "bashrc" at "/home/<user>/git/homedirsync/ansible/roles/common/tasks/bashrc"
looking for "bashrc" at "/home/<user>/git/homedirsync/ansible/roles/common/tasks/files/bashrc"
looking for "bashrc" at "/home/<user>/git/homedirsync/ansible/roles/common/tasks/bashrc"
 [WARNING]: Unable to find 'bashrc' in expected paths
...
```

Ansible version:

```
ansible 2.6.1
  config file = /home/<user>/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/var/ansible/library']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.6 (default, Nov 13 2018, 12:45:42) [GCC 4.8.4]
```

I saw a lot of examples where it works and issues where it doesn't, but I can't localize the root of problem in my case. Community, please help.

Comment: can you please try copying the files from `bashrc` folder to the `files` folder ?

Comment: @error404, if I write `src: bashrc/shell-aliases.lib.sh` and `dest: shell-aliases.lib.sh` then ansible falls to error with long pythonic fallback trace, but says `looking for "bashrc/shell-aliases.lib.sh" at "/home/viktorkho/git/homedirsync/ansible/roles/common/tasks/files/bashrc/shell-aliases.lib.sh"`

Comment: you have to remove `bashrc/` just keep the `*.lib.sh`

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Unable to find subdir in expected paths with fileglob"*

A: Quoting from [fileglob's NOTES](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/fileglob.html#notes)

> *"Matching is against local system files on the Ansible controller. "*

Role's feature "Any copy, script, template or include tasks can reference files in roles/x/{files,templates,tasks} ..." does not apply to *fileglob*.

Instead, it's possible to use [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables). For example

```
with_fileglob:
  - '{{ role_path }}/files/bashrc/*.lib.sh'
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but rigth now I can't check it cos I guessed to update ansible, and now I have some portion of new problems.. sorry, I will come back later